# Find And Replace Value after colon in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a file like this

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: myDb
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ea64f518be08e0d5895335990f10d984c22f400c
    name_db: newDB
```

This is a yml file, and it has a particular format

I Want to create a file sh that find and replace the value after `name_db` with a parameter

Comment: too broad! Better show your attempts

Comment: something like `sed -i 's/newDb/myNewDb/g' file.yml` but newDb takes by RegExp and the value myNewDb by parameter

Comment: Like @monkeyUser said, but with more care:  `sed -i '/ +name_db: / s,newDb,myNewDb,' file.yml`. I swapped the '/'s for ','s because I think they're easier to parse in scripts. Also, I dropped the [g]lobal since you're probably never going to use that here.

Comment: This `;` is a semicolon; this `:` is a colon btw

Comment: @Harvey `sed: 1: "file.yml": extra characters at the end of p command`. Anyway I want to replace any value after name_db colon. In this case is newDB, after could be mynewdb with mynewdb2 etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for the key (`name_db:`) and replace the value after it.  Assuming a `sed` that supports the `-i` option:

```
sed -i.bak "/^[[:space:]]*name_db:/ s/:.*/: $newname/" file.yml
```

The regular expression `/^[[:space:]]*name_db:/` looks for a line that starts with zero or more spaces followed by `name_db:`.  When that line is found, the `s/:.*/: $newname/` substitute is executed.  It will replace the colon and whatever follows with colon, space, and the value in `$newname`.  This will fail if `$newname` contains a slash.  If that's a possibility, choose a different character (other than `/`) as the marker.  In case of doubt, <kbd>Control-A</kbd> is quite useful and unlikely to be part of a valid `name_db` value.

This doesn't care what the old value is. You can simply wrap this whole expression in double quotes, which interpolates the value in `$newname`.  Nevertheless, using single quotes around `sed` scripts is generally a good idea.

---

[monkeyUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3429219/monkeyuser) commented:

> `sed: 1: "file.yml": extra characters at the end of p command`

Note that the command line shown (using `-i.bak`) works on both Linux (GNU `sed`) and Mac OS X (BSD `sed`).  GNU `sed` allows an optional backup suffix which must be attached to the `-i` option if it is present; BSD `sed` requires a suffix which must either be attached to the `-i` option as shown or can be the next argument.  If you want no backup with GNU `sed`, specify just `-i …`; with BSD `sed`, specify `''` as an empty argument after the `-i` option: `-i '' …`.  Given the error message `sed: 1: "file.yml": extra characters at the end of p command`, I'm suspicious that the code was run on a system with BSD `sed`, though I'm not quite sure why `p` was mentioned (I suspect some editing of the actual error message).  That is: `sed -i /something/ file.yml` would, with BSD `sed`, treat `/something/` as the backup file suffix and then find problems with `file.yml` treated as a `sed` script…except I think the file name began with `p` rather than `f`, since `f` isn't a `sed` command (but `p` is).

Comment: Perfect ! Can you give me a little explanation?

Comment: Thanks again, I want to change several values in the same file. I do something like this `#!/bin/bash
sed -i.bak "/^[[:space:]]*name_db:/s/:.*/: $1/" app/config/parameters.yml
sed -i.bak "/^[[:space:]]*user_db:/s/:.*/: $2/" app/config/parameters.yml
sed -i.bak "/^[[:space:]]*pass_db:/s/:.*/: $3/" app/config/parameters.yml`.
Can I do all in one command?

Comment: Yup.  Use `-e 'cmd1' -e 'cmd2'`, etc, where the commands are the match-and-substitute commands.  Or place the commands in a file (`sed.script`) and use `-f sed.script`.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot ! Do you have any book to advice me to learn this commands?