# How to find and replace a string having particular pattern with same string

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file with values as

```
localhost haproxy[110378]:{Lionuk:1234567890} "POST /artim-decision/rs/interaction/Lionuk:1234567890/SendData;channel=fdmobile;inp=fdmobilea?version=2&trace=0 HTTP/1.1"

localhost haproxy[110378]:{Lionuk:3456789012} "GET /artim-decision/rs/interaction/Lionuk:3456789012/TargetedMessages;channel=MOBILE;inp=hsbcmobileoverlay?version=2&trace=0 HTTP/1.1"
```

I am looking for a command which can search for all pattern starting with `Lionuk:` and replace it with  `Tiger`.

I am trying as below but it is not working as  I want

```
sed -E 's/\(.*\)Lionuk:\(.*\)/\Tiger\2/g' File.txt
```

Below is the output

```
Tiger1234567890/SendData;channel=fdmobile;inp=fdmobilea?version=2&trace=0 HTTP/1.1"
Tiger3456789012/TargetedMessages;channel=MOBILE;inp=hsbcmobileoverlay?version=2&trace=0 HTTP/1.1"
```

Expected outout is

```
localhost haproxy[110378]:{Tiger} "POST /artim-decision/rs/interaction/Tiger/SendData;channel=fdmobile;inp=fdmobilea?version=2&trace=0 HTTP/1.1"
localhost haproxy[110378]:{Tiger} "GET /artim-decision/rs/interaction/Tiger/TargetedMessages;channel=MOBILE;inp=hsbcmobileoverlay?version=2&trace=0 HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find And Replace Value after colon in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057200/find-and-replace-value-after-colon-in-bash-script)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some example input, the actual output you get and the expected output. To me it is not clear if you want to replace `Lionuk` or the variable part after the colon or the complete value. It is also not clear if there can be additional text before or after the value.

Comment: I have changed the question. Please provide your input now.

Comment: Please format your question, as it is, it is difficult to read. Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) if you don't know how. The problem with your sed command is that you forgot a character. It is `\1Tiger...`, not `\Tiger`.

Comment: Please specify in your question if the variable part after `Lionuk:` will always consist of digits only or what else characters are possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i -e 's/Lionuk/Tiger/g' File.txt
```

Read more about it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159369/451307